# Copying attributes from many columns to one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, copy

I have many columns, about 30 and each of those has some attributes. I want to merge those columns into one and collect all attributes in a row of columns. I tried with this post [Combining Columns QGIS Attribute Table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287963/combining-columns-qgis-attribute-table) but it is not for what I am looking for.

I have an example in MS Excel that I want that without commas and spaces. Attributes have to be separated with one comma.

[image]

With this script, if some fields are empty, I have got `NULL` fields.

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the expressions `coalesce` and `try`?

Comment: I used coalesce, but only first attribute was copied

Comment: Please provide the expression you used.

Comment: coalesce(  "spec"  ,   "spec_1"  ,  "spec_12"  , "spec_1_13"   ,   "spec_1_14"   ,   "spec_1_15" , "spec_1_16"  ,    "spec_1_17"   ,  "spec_1_18" , "spec_1_19"  ,    "spec_1_20"  ,   "spec_1_21" , "spec_1_22" ,   "spec_1_23"   ,  "spec_1_24" , "spec_1_25"   ,  "spec_1_26"  ,  "spec_1_27" , "spec_1_28"  ,    "spec_1_29"  ,  "spec_1_30" , "spec_1_31"  ,   "spec_1_32"  ,   "spec_1_33" , '0')

Comment: Yeah, and have you read how the expression works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression does the trick

```
array_filter(
    map_avals(
        attributes()
        ),
    @element <> ''
    )
```

1. [`attributes()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#attributes) : get all fields with their corresponding values
2. [`map_avals()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#map-avals) : gives you just the values as an array
3. [`array_filter(array, expression)`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-filter) : the expression `@element <> ''` filters out the empty values

Comment: With this : array_filter( map_avals( attributes( )), @element <>''), I got empty fields. I forgot to say, some columns are in between that I have to exclude from those columns. I have to pick columns manually, (by hand). Something like the second picture

Comment: Nice expression! `array_to_string( array_filter ... )` converts the array to a string. It works in QGIS 3.10, latest QGIS LTR 3.4.13 doesn't have the `attributes()` function.